# How really static synchronized method works in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to explore `static synchronized method` I got the theoretical concept that it's acquire lock on class, not on instance. But I'm failed to create an example where I Can test it.

Here I have created the Code to test, But both instance are accessing `static synchronized method` at the same time.

```
class Demo{
    public static synchronized void a(){
        System.out.println("A Method " +  Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
public class StaticSyn{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Demo obj = new Demo();
        Demo obj2 = new Demo();

        Thread one = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                int i=0;
                while(i<5){
                    obj.a();
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){

                }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        };
        Thread two = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                int i=0;
                while(i<5){
                    obj2.a();
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){     }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        });

        one.start();
        two.start();
    }
}
```

With `static synchronized` I'm getting this output.

```
A Method Thread-0
A Method Thread-1
A Method Thread-1
A Method Thread-0
A Method Thread-1
A Method Thread-0
A Method Thread-0
A Method Thread-1
A Method Thread-1
A Method Thread-0
```

Without `static` keyword I'm getting this output.

```
A Method Thread-0
A Method Thread-1
A Method Thread-1
A Method Thread-0
A Method Thread-0
A Method Thread-1
A Method Thread-0
A Method Thread-1
A Method Thread-1
A Method Thread-0
```

So, where is the problem? and How I can test that Just one object is accessing static synchronized method.

Comment: A `static synchronized` method in `Demo` is equivalent to wrapping the method body in `synchronized (Demo.class) { ... }`.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes I know, but why both thread are accessing same method with different object?

Comment: There is no problem, neither of your threads is *inside* `a()` while the other is.

Comment: What are you actually *expecting* to happen?

Comment: And because `System.out` is internally synchronized already, there will be no difference whether `Demo.a()` is synchronized or not.

Comment: @AndyTurner I want the code where I can test that Only one thread can access `static synchronized method`

Comment: @LetDoit but what does that mean? `synchronized` doesn't mean only one thread can run it, it means that only one thread can run it at once - which it is doing.

Comment: I'd add that calling a static method on object instances is a code smell (at least a compiler warning in Java), your grasp on "what you want to achieve" does not seem good enough just yet.

Comment: @GPI I want `static synchronized method` and `synchronized method` example in practical.. mean in code that could describe different between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `sleep` in your method `a()` as next:

```
public static synchronized void a(){
    System.out.println("Before sleep: A Method " +  Thread.currentThread().getName());
    try{
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch(InterruptedException e){
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    System.out.println("After sleep: A Method " +  Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

You will then see that you won't have 2 threads executing this block at the same time like in the next output, indeed you never have twice consecutively `Before sleep`:

```
Before sleep: A Method Thread-0
After sleep: A Method Thread-0
Before sleep: A Method Thread-1
After sleep: A Method Thread-1
Before sleep: A Method Thread-0
After sleep: A Method Thread-0
Before sleep: A Method Thread-1
After sleep: A Method Thread-1
Before sleep: A Method Thread-0
After sleep: A Method Thread-0
Before sleep: A Method Thread-1
After sleep: A Method Thread-1
Before sleep: A Method Thread-0
After sleep: A Method Thread-0
Before sleep: A Method Thread-1
After sleep: A Method Thread-1
Before sleep: A Method Thread-0
After sleep: A Method Thread-0
Before sleep: A Method Thread-1
After sleep: A Method Thread-1
```

What is the difference between `static synchronized` method and `synchronized` method?

The main difference is the object used to synchronize the access.

**Static**

For example doing this:

```
class Demo {
    public static synchronized void a() {
        // Rest of the method
    }
}
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
class Demo {
    public static void a() {
        synchronized (Demo.class) {
            // Rest of the method
        }
    }
}
```

In other words in case of a `static` method it uses the object representing the class itself to synchronize the access.

**Non Static**

For example doing this:

```
class Demo {
    public synchronized void a() {
        // Rest of the method
    }
}
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
class Demo {
    public void a() {
        synchronized (this) {
            // Rest of the method
        }
    }
}
```

In other words in case of a `non static` method it uses the current instance of the class to synchronize the access.

Comment: Really thanks it clearing, but little confused. can you write an example of `static synchronized method` and `synchronized method` in code that could describe difference between them.

Comment: sure, hold on a little bit

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `a()` method run long to make sure the method calls aren't overlapping. This is one way of doing it:

```
package com.example;

public class Demo {

    public static synchronized void a() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("A Method " +  Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Demo obj = new Demo();
        final Demo obj2 = new Demo();

        Thread one = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                obj.a(); // same as Demo.run() 
            }
        };
        Thread two = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                obj2.a(); // same as Demo.run() 
            }
        };

        one.start();
        two.start();
    }
}
```